# counter in php when client press button

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I have this part of code in php . when player press button in client (using ajax) I want my database show next record. but I won't.

```
if(isset($_POST['req'])){

$counter++;

$sql = "SELECT question FROM mytable WHERE id = $counter";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["id"]." ". $row["question"]. " " . "<br>";
}
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}

}
```

Comment: How do you initialise `$counter`? Try printing its value after `$counter++;` and check which one it gets

Comment: maybe it 's not correct to use 'if'. 
for example counter is 0 first time. and when counter++ , it will be 1. but it never increase anymore. what 's the correct way to code for this ?

Comment: @Nico should it be increased every time that req comes?
$counter is 1 first , it become 2 for second and stop increasing and stay 2!

Comment: When you are using `++` it is always necessary to initialize the variable you are `++`ing, otherwise you will get unpredictable result. However assuming `$counter` is initialised to 0 this code will always set `$counter` to 1 So you may as well hardcode the query

Comment: It's not because of the `if`. What you need is either a global variable or a counter in your DB.

Comment: @RiggsFolly   I put $counter = 1; up my php. and it may always execute it.
where can I put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest storing your counter in a session. Then each time a player does this action you can give them the next row like so :-

```
session_start();


if(isset($_POST['req'])){

    if ( ! isset($_SESSION['counter']) ) {
        $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT question FROM mytable WHERE id = {$_SESSION['counter']}";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ( ! $result ) {
        // log error to error log
        error_log(print_r($conn->errorinfo(),true), 3, 'app_error.log');
        echo "Temporary database issues, please try again later";
        header('Location: error_page.php');
        exit;
    }

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo $row["id"]." ". $row["question"]. " " . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to send the current id along in the Ajax request. Increment it then use it to pull the next question from your database

Comment: ajax is available for client . so s.b would change it and get some points in the game !